# What should I do if password_hash isn't supported

Tags: php, password-protection, password-hash

I have a web server that runs PHP 5.4.x, which means it doesn't support the password_hash function, so I can't hash passwords. 
I cannot upgrade the PHP version.

How can I *protect* passwords without the password_hash function ?

Comment: Did you try to implement the hash function in a helper function? Not necessarily you need to update PHP. Have a look at the Wikipedia page for some concrete example of hashing algorithms. Here the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function.

Comment: If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

> This library is intended to provide forward compatibility with the password_* functions that ship with PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [crypt function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

You can also use [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). It's a backward compatible library to emulate [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) in older versions of PHP (5.3.7+).